# SVN - How to work with directories containing @ sign?

Tags: svn, matlab

--
Hi Everyone

I have a directory called temp and I want to rename it @Controller (it's a matlab thing, don't ask).

But when I run:
$ svn move temp @Controller

SVN gives me a weird error about a missing peg?

I also tried
$ svn move temp @Controller@

Because I read SVN only looks at the last at sign, but that moved the folder to @Controller@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion uses @ for a special purpose.

The solution is what you did: add an `@` at the end (but it sounds like it should have made it `@Controller`)

[Peg and Operative Revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.pegrevs)

> The perceptive reader is probably wondering at this point whether the peg revision syntax causes problems for working copy paths or URLs that actually have at signs in them. After all, how does svn know whether news@11 is the name of a directory in my tree or just a syntax for “revision 11 of news”? Thankfully, while svn will always assume the latter, there is a trivial workaround. You need only append an at sign to the end of the path, such as news@11@. svn cares only about the last at sign in the argument, and it is not considered illegal to omit a literal peg revision specifier after that at sign. This workaround even applies to paths that end in an at sign—you would use filename@@ to talk about a file named filename@.

Comment: I just tried this with `svn 1.7.2`, and it worked as expected (even recommended using a @ at the end when I did not use it).

Comment: Hmm, perhaps it is in a bug in 1.6.  I'm going to upgrade and then I'm going to accept your answer.  Thank you.

Comment: With 1.7, there are changes to the working copy, so you will need to update the working copy before you can do anything else. Also, you will also want to update any other Subversion tools you use (such as AnkhSVN, TortoiseSVN, etc.) so they will work with the updated working copies.